# Running c# programs on startup

Tags: c#, bash, macos, automation

I just made a c# application to organize my desktop, if I run it in the terminal

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono Program.exe`

my program runs as normal, so I wanted to automate the startup with the Mac automator. The bash commands get greenlit but when I open the application it opens and then stops immediately. Am I doing anything wrong or is there a different way to run my script on startup.
Here is the main piece of my c# code, if it helps I can put paste all of it here.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = "/Users/user/Desktop/SortTheseFiles";
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileChanged;
        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileChanged;
        fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileChanged;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcherDownloads = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcherDownloads.Path = "/Users/user/Downloads";
        fileSystemWatcherDownloads.Created += DownloadsChanged;
        fileSystemWatcherDownloads.Changed += DownloadsChanged;
        fileSystemWatcherDownloads.Renamed += DownloadsChanged;
        fileSystemWatcherDownloads.Deleted += DownloadsChanged;
        fileSystemWatcherDownloads.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some extra digging I found it's possible with apple script. Here is my code

```
tell application "Terminal"
    reopen
    activate
    do script "cd /Users/user/Desktop/CleanMyMac/CleanMyMac/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1" in window 1
    do script "dotnet CleanMyMac.dll" in window 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this with Automator but you asked for another way:

I made a tool called [RepoZ](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ) I wanted to start with macOS, too. This works by throwing [a launch agent file](https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ/blob/master/_ref/macOS/net.sodacore.RepoZ.plist) to `/Library/LaunchAgents/`.